# Obtaining the limit of sequence $\prod_{k=n+1}^{k=2n} (1-\tfrac{1}{k^2})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have this sequence and I'm trying to calculate its limit

$$\prod_{k=n+1}^{k=2n} (1-\tfrac{1}{k^2})$$
anyone have an idea how can I solve this?
thanks for the help

Comment: Isn't $\prod_{k=2}^\infty(1-1/k^2)$ absolutely convergent?

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown The product is from $k=n+1$ to $k=2n$, thus it does not look the same issue as the classical infinite product you mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\prod_{k\geq 2}\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$ is a convergent product, convergent to $\frac{1}{2}$ by telescoping, or by De l'Hopital theorem and the Weierstrass product for the sine function, if you like an overkill. In particular
$$ \sum_{k\geq 2}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right) $$
is a convergent series, and its partial sums form a Cauchy sequence:
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right)=0. $$ 
By exponentiating both sides,
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\prod_{k=n+1}^{2n}\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right) = 1. $$

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

\begin{align}a_n &= \prod_{i=1}^n \left( 1 - \frac{1}{(n+i)^2}\right) \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n \left(  \frac{(n+i+1)(n+i-1)}{(n+i)^2}\right)\end{align}

\begin{align} \ln a_n 
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left[\ln(n+i+1) - 2\ln (n+i)+\ln(n+i-1)\right]\end{align}

Try telescoping.

Comment: You won ! Cheers.

Comment: is there a way to calculate it without using ln? maybe with the squeeze sentence?

Comment: You can just cancel out terms from product form directly, it's just my habit to take log.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k\ =\ n + 1}^{k\ =\ 2n}\pars{1 - {1 \over k^{2}}} & =
{\bracks{\prod_{k\ =\ n + 1}^{k\ =\ 2n}\pars{k - 1}}
\bracks{\prod_{k\ =\ n + 1}^{k\ =\ 2n}\pars{k + 1}} \over
\pars{\prod_{k\ =\ n + 1}^{k\ =\ 2n}k}^{2}} =
{n^{\large\overline{n}}\pars{n + 2}^{\large\overline{n}} \over
\bracks{\pars{n + 1}^{\large\overline{n}}}^{2}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] & =
{\bracks{\Gamma\pars{2n}/\Gamma\pars{n}}
\bracks{\Gamma\pars{2n + 2}/\Gamma\pars{n + 2}} \over
\bracks{\Gamma\pars{2n + 1}/\Gamma\pars{n + 1}}^{\,2}}
\\[5mm] & =
{\Gamma\pars{2n}\Gamma\pars{2n + 2}\Gamma^{2}\pars{n + 1} \over
\Gamma\pars{n}\Gamma\pars{n + 2}\Gamma^{2}\pars{2n + 1}}
=
{\bracks{\pars{2n}!/\pars{2n}}\bracks{2n\pars{2n}!}\pars{n!}^{2} \over
\bracks{n!/n}\bracks{\pars{n + 1}n!}\bracks{\pars{2n}!}^{\,2}}
\\[5mm] & =
{n \over n + 1}\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\to}\,\,\,
\bbx{1}
\end{align}

> Indeed, the task simplest way is the 'telescoping manipulation' of second expression in \eqref{1}.